# LinearLayout transperancy issue?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i know their many question about this and i have tried some of them but none is working for me. 
 I have layout file, the layout structure is like this

[image]

l2 is on top of l1, i want to change the transparency l2 around 40 to 5o percent dynamically. So that the layout l1 which is behind l2 little visible. Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AlphaAnimation with duration = 0 to set a certain transparency on a view:

```
AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.5);
animation.setDuration(0);
animation.setFillAfter(true);

ln2.startAnimation(animation);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for quick response, let me try this.

Comment: can i make this animation keep running until a specific event happen. because it just disappear after a sec

Comment: working perfect thanks and one more thing it's not ln1.startAnimation(animation) it's actually ln2.startAnimation(animation)

Comment: ah, sorry... didn't pay attention to that. but anyway, glad I could help :)